# How to break up my monolithic repository?

Tags: tfs, version-control, branching-and-merging

I have several projects, Project A through E, and all reference project J and K.  Project A through E all change at different intervals.  But the changes to any of them almost always require changes to Project J and/or K.  Project A through E are web apps, and Project J and K are business /data layers.

**So, should Project J and K live in their own respective repos? And Projects A through E live in their respective Repos?**

Ideally, I'd like to achieve the ability to branch by feature and require pull requests to merge back into main.

Developer 1 may be working on Project A and B.  Developer 2 may be working on Project A and D.  Developer 3 may only work on Project C.  And Project E may not change at all.  But Project J and K will most likely change.

**I am primarily trying to figure out how to separate my monolithic repository into pieces to facility branch by feature.**

Comment: So all the projects are independent?

Comment: A through E don't care about each other.  But they care about J and K.  Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can place all the projects in their own respective repos and use [Git Submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for Project J and K.